# Cannot run program "osascript": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, selenium, applescript, appium, osascript

I am trying to run the following piece of applescript in a selenium test hosted on a remote grid.

```
protected void enableTouchIDLogin(){
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   String appleScriptCommand =   "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Simulator\"\n" +
                   "click menu item \"Touch ID Enrolled\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \"Hardware\" of menu bar 1\n"+
                   "end tell";


   String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", appleScriptCommand};
   try
   {
     Process process = runtime.exec(args);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

When I run the test locally it works fine. But on the remote grid I get

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "osascript": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)`

I'm not sure why this is the case. On the remote grid 'which osascript' returns ' /usr/bin/osascript.' which is the same location for my osascript when running locally.

Given that the path both locally and on the remote grid is the same i'm not sure why the -e flag doesnt work. I'm not sure what my appleScriptCommand should look like...

EDIT

As per one of the replies here i tried the following which doesn't throw an error but also doesn't perform the functionality locally or remotely.

```
  protected void enableTouchIDLogin(){



   try
   {
       Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
       String appleScriptCommand =   "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Simulator\"\n" +
                       "click menu item \"Touch ID Enrolled\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \"Hardware\" of menu bar 1\n"+
                       "end tell";

       File executor = File.createTempFile("exec", ".sh");
       PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(executor, "UTF-8");
       writer.println("#!/bin/bash");
       writer.println();
       writer.println(String.format("osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"%s\\\" with administrator privileges\"",
                       appleScriptCommand));
       writer.close();
       executor.setExecutable(true);

       Process process = runtime.exec(String.format("%s",
                       executor.getPath()));
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }
```

Comment: i changed my code, try the new one now ;)

Comment: new update :) look down

Answer (score 0):

This works good for me
UPDATE5:

```
String script = "tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to tell process \\\"Simulator\\\"\n" +
                   "click menu item \\\"Touch ID Enrolled\\\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \\\"Hardware\\\" of menu bar 1\n"+
                   "end tell";
File executor = File.createTempFile("exec", ".sh");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(executor, "UTF-8");
writer.println("#!/bin/bash");
writer.println();
writer.println(String.format("osascript -e \"%s\" with administrator privileges",
        script);
writer.close();
executor.setExecutable(true);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("%s", 
        executor.getPath()));
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work for me....I've updated my question to reflect this code. This doesn't throw an error but it also just doesn't do anything at all for me

Comment: I've updated my code in this way too. Now locally, it asks me to type in my password to allow changes to be made....but on Saucelabs, which is the remote grid I am running on, this prompt never appears the commands never run.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work.. Maybe be try with it:

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work.. your script is an osascript ? Then try my new update...

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. It is an osascript and it runs fine locally from the beginning. Just remotely is the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work in my local now nor on the remote grid I am running.